# Centring Android Drawable XML logo in Toolbar

Tags: android, toolbar, android-appcompat

I am trying to centre an android drawable XML resource in a toolbar. The toolbar was generated from the navigation drawer activity ‘template’ in android studio 1.5.

**Example:**

*What I am getting:*
[image]

*What I am aiming for:*

[image]

My current code centres the resource vertically but not horizontally, I have searched high and low for a way to centre the resource, however I have found no solution. I have also tried centring the resource file as an image view in the toolbars associated XML code, however, the image centres but is on the bottom of the toolbar (centres horizontally but not vertically).

**Current Code:**
*NavigationDrawerActivity*

```
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_navigation_drawer);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle(null);
        toolbar.setLogo(R.drawable.app_logo);
```

*app_bar_navigation_drawer.xml*  **(*Default*)**

```
    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"/>
</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can edit your Toolbar since it's derived from `ViewGroup` to something like this.

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:contentDescription="@string/logo"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"/>

 </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

Comment: Thank You for your answer! *Facepalms* I don't know how I didn't see this. Thank You for pointing that out, and excuse my ignorance. lol.

Comment: No problem, if it worked you can accept the answer as a thanks.